# How can I use history.push('path') in react router 5.1.2 in stateful component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I use history.push('path') in react router 5.1.2 in stateful component (class component)?

I found this, but it is a solution for a stateless component.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let history = useHistory();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how you can navigate to other components using **`history.push("/...")`**

In v6, use **`navigate("/...")`** in the functional component using **`useNavigation()`** hook.

In react-router-dom v6, **`useHistory()`** has been replaced to **`useNavigation()`** hook that's why **`history.push("/...")`** can't be used anymore as per the official React router documentation.

For better understanding, refer to [Official Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.11.2/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory)

```
const BasicExample = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
const Header = () => (
  <ul className="navbar">
    <li>
      <NavLink to="/"> Home </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink to="/about"> About </NavLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
);
const About = () => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgreen", height: "100vh" }}>
    <div>About</div>
    ....
  </div>
);

const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate("/about");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to navigate about page</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Live Demo in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-46dw8)

**Class component**

For class-based component, you can use like this

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: `/path-name`,
    state: data_to_pass //You can pass data to the component where you are navigating
});
```

But in v6, You can use **`Navigation`** element to navigate to other components.

**Example**

Set `isOk` state true to navigate **About** component.

```
{this.state.isOk && <Navigate to="/about" replace={true} />}
```

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue when using react router v5.
When trying to change route programmatically below,

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: `/target-path`,
    state: variable_to_transfer
});
```

*this.props.history* was ***undefined***.

Here is my solution for react router v5.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyClass extends Component {
    routingFunction = (param) => {
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: `/target-path`,
            state: param
        });
    }
    ...
}
export default withRouter(MyClass);
```

Here is [reference article](https://medium.com/teamsubchannel/react-component-patterns-e7fb75be7bb0).
Hope it helps you save your time.

**Update for *Next.js***
You should use withRouter from 'next/router' in Next.js.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyClass extends Component {
  routingFunction = (param) => {
     this.props.router.push('/dashboard');
  }
  ...
}
export default withRouter(MyClass);
```

Comment: The key important point in this example is that withRouter() creates a new higher-order-component that will have three new props: match, location, and history.

Comment: You really saved my time. I spent almost one day to figure out this. By the way I am new to react env

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have the reputation to comment on an answer, this is an
> addition to akhtarvahid's answer.

Here is some information you might find useful  automatically give these values in props, to use the Route functionalities :

```
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
```

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

> {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object,
> staticContext:undefined}

The examples above only work if you don't want to add any other value in props.
if we pass our component to Route as a child, the rendering is done correctly and the route works.

```
<Route exact path="/" > <Home name="toto" /></Route>
```

But in this case Route will not pass the props to our component so we will not have histoy, location ect...

> {name: "foo"}

if you use
this.props.history.push("/about");
this will generate an error because history was not added to the component

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Here is a solution that allows the Route component with a callback

```
   <Exact route path="/"
  
   render={(props) =><Home name="foo" {...props}/>}
   ></Road>
```

> {name:"foo", match: Object, location: Object, history: Object,
> staticContext:undefined}

Answer (score -2):

Just wrap everything within **<BrowserRouter>** and use **<useHistory>** to create a object literal like:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...
...
return(
   <BrowserRouter>
      ...
      ...
   </BrowserRouter>
)
```

and in the function, use:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
...
...
const history = useHistory();

function handlePush() {
...
history.push('/url');
...
}
```

This should pretty much workout for you.
Happy to help.  by RTTSS.

Comment: The issue is about stateful components. We can't use hooks for them